# Why the extra compact dimensions of superstring theory must form a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification, calabi-yau

In superstring theory, extra dimensions are conjectured. Then, the obvious observation that, macroscopically, we observe only three spacelike dimensions and one timelike dimension, leads to the requirement that, locally, the space-time of superstring theory admits a topological trivialitization of the form $\mathcal{M}\times \mathcal{K}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is a four-dimensional [Lorentzian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold) and $\mathcal{K}$ is small compact manifold (whose physical radius should be significantly smaller than $10^{-19}\ \text{m}$, the length scale currently being explored).

In most version of superstring theory $\mathcal{K}$ is taken as a Calabi-Yau [Kähler manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold), who is a special case of Riemann manifold with [zero Ricci curvature (Ricci flat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci-flat_manifold). My question is:

What physical restrictions lead to the requierement of Ricci flatness of $\mathcal{K}$?

(**this question is not a duplicate**, I am asking for the reasons for zero Ricci curvature, not for the compactification itself).

Comment: Ricci-flatness is a corollary of requiring a covariantly constant spinor for unbroken N=1 SUSY in the compactified theory.